# What's the easiest way to look up a transaction on the blockchain?

Tags: block-explorer, implementation

If I want to check if my transaction has made it to the blockchain, where can I look it up and by what data can I search/filter? Of course there is the transaction id and possibly a payment id, but is there other data I could use to find my transaction?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. "is there other data I could use to find my transaction?" - well, whatever data you happen to have is what you could use. You should rephrase that to be clearer.

Comment: Is there something unsatisfactory with my answer? It's been several weeks and it's helpful to either receive feedback or have it marked as correct.

Comment: nope, there isn't anything unsatifactory :) not sure how I missed this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best general tool for this is http://moneroblocks.info/.  It is somewhat comparable to the Bitcoin site https://blockchain.info/, and you can conduct searches using a number of different identifiers.

However, if you are focusing on a specific transaction, I think your best bet might actually be a very useful tool developed by one of our community members: http://xmrtests.llcoins.net/checktx.html

By using the transaction hash, viewkey or private transaction key, and the recipient's public address you can prove that a transaction made it to its intended destination.